# WebStorm - debugger terminates a process on breakpoints. Process finished with exit code -1073741510

Tags: javascript, debugging, intellij-idea, webstorm

Today, my WebStorm started to behave weird. When I stop it on breakpoint - process falls. It occurs at any breakpoint. I work with nodejs javascript.

I tried to record gif, but quality is very bad (sorry for that), however, you can imagine the problem if you look at the gif.
[image: Process interrupted after breakpoint]
As you can see here: debugger caught a breakpoint, but then, process just stopped. At the bottom of the webstorm it is written: "Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)".

Everything worked perfectly yesterday, what can be wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem occurs because of one of the old watched expressions. I just deleted them all and now debugger works again.

Comment: @Andrevinsky, I'm glad to hear it :)

Comment: I deleted all the breakpoints and restarted the IDE, but the solution didn't work for me.

Comment: So frustrating. Thanks for the tip Alendorff

Comment: Deleting some (invalid) breakpoints in `Run/View Breakpoints ...` did the trick for me. There where two breakpoints that had no code in the preview window. Their name was also mentioned in a tooltip to the Debug tab every time the node crashed ...

Answer (score 0):

Things I tried (the last thing worked, naturally)

- Deleting all breakpoints
- Deleting all watchers
- restarting
- removing a console.log statement I had added (seemed to addle the debugger)