# WebStorm debugger not working when debuggin NPM script, saying Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

my webstorm debugger works fine if I simply run, say, my `server.js` directly in debug mode.
However, when I run an NPM script in debug mode (`npm start` for instance), I get the following exception:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

I use Webstorm WebStorm 2016.1.2
Build #WS-145.971, built on May 1, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_77-b03 x86
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation

My Node version is 5.11.0

I run it Windows 7, my colleague is running Windows 10 with same problem.

Did anyone come across this problem yet?

Comment: can't recreate. Sample project would be helpful

Comment: What is strange is, at a colleagues PC it works, with the same project.

Comment: Does he use the same Node.js version?

Comment: indeed we have some discrepancies in the used Node version. I will investigate that..

Answer (score 0):

there could be many reasons for this - here are just some of my thoughts which may be useful to someone:

maybe **some problem of the IDE**: e.g. in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29589044/1041641) caused by old watch variables

- try to clear the ide/debugger state: e.g. delete breakpoints, watches, etc.
- try: `Invalidate caches / Restart`

maybe just an **early exit**
I had one case in our node-tests, where some part of the code just called `process.exit(0)` before the async test-function had finished. This also caused the (confusing) console output:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

Comment: Deleting some (invalid) breakpoints in `Run/View Breakpoints ...` did the trick for me. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29589044/3102305